# LARAVEL Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::splice()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to select some atributes of the table Animals and at the same time selecting their photos.

The problem is that in my case I want to select 20 animals depending on the page (For example, if I am in page 2 I want to take the animals between 20-40

I am doing an splice for that, but I don't know how to make it work, it throws me that error.

Anyobody knows why or how?

Many thanks in advance!
[image: Code]

$cantidad is the quantity of animals I want to take
$pagina is the page

Comment: Can you please edit the question and share actual code rather than pictures of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be aware of the class you're working with, especially `Builder` vs `Collection`

All queries in Laravel (`Animal::select(...)`) are instances of the `Builder` class until a closure (`->get()`, `->first()`, etc) is called. Since you're not using one of those closures before calling `->splice()`, you're attempting to call this method on a class (`Builder`) that doesn't have it. The `Collection` class has this method:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-splice

So you need to use `->get()` before `->splice()`:

```
return Animal::select(...)
->join(...)
->where(...)
->get()
->splice(...)
->toJson();
```

Comment: Also if you use splice for pagination, that means you are querying all posts in all pages. Better use Skip and Take methods. Even better use ->paginate() function.

Comment: @M.Tahir Totally agreed; there are better implementations available for pagination, but this is primarily for addressing the specific issue here :)

Comment: Yeap, just saying :)

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for explaining! It worked flawlesly!

Comment: Also I will try to improve the pagination because as you say there are better ways! Thanks

Comment: @PacoPinazoGuna No problem! Understanding the current class, especially with method chaining like this is something that comes with practice, but eventually it'll make perfect sense :) And yeah, this works for smaller tables, but once you get into a large amount of records, this approach will grind to a halt.